# Archlinux Kernel: Module ipv6 not found

Tags: arch-linux, ipv6, kernel-module

I found that I can't reach ipv6 network normally when I use archlinux:

```sh
$ ssh root@[ipv6 addr]
ssh: connect to host [ipv6 addr] port 22: Network is unreachable
```

After further inspection, I think the kernel module for ipv6 is not open normally:

```sh
$ test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo 1                                                                                                                         
1
$ lsmod | grep ipv6
# nothing
$ modinfo ipv6
modinfo: ERROR: Module ipv6 not found.
```

I went to further check my `/etc/modprobe.d/mobprobe.conf` configuration files and kernel directories, the following is the result:

```sh
# /etc/modprobe.d/mobprobe.conf
options snd-hda-intel model=,generic
```

```sh
$ find /lib/modules/ -name ipv6.ko
# nothing
$ ls /lib/modules/4.19.69-1-lts/kernel/net/ipv6
ah6.ko.xz   esp6_offload.ko.xz  ila            ip6_tunnel.ko.xz      ip6_vti.ko.xz  mip6.ko.xz  sit.ko.xz      xfrm6_mode_beet.ko.xz  xfrm6_mode_transport.ko.xz  xfrm6_tunnel.ko.xz
esp6.ko.xz  fou6.ko.xz          ip6_gre.ko.xz  ip6_udp_tunnel.ko.xz  ipcomp6.ko.xz  netfilter   tunnel6.ko.xz  xfrm6_mode_ro.ko.xz    xfrm6_mode_tunnel.ko.xz
```

So what should I do next?

---

Thank you for your reply!

More Info:

- Kernel version: 4.19.69-1-lts
- `cat /proc/cmdline`

```sh
initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux-lts.img root=/dev/nvme0n1p7
```

- `gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep "CONFIG_IPV6"`

```sh
CONFIG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTE_INFO=y
CONFIG_IPV6_OPTIMISTIC_DAD=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MIP6=m
CONFIG_IPV6_ILA=m
CONFIG_IPV6_VTI=m
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT=m
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT_6RD=y
CONFIG_IPV6_NDISC_NODETYPE=y
CONFIG_IPV6_TUNNEL=m
CONFIG_IPV6_GRE=m
CONFIG_IPV6_FOU=m
CONFIG_IPV6_FOU_TUNNEL=m
CONFIG_IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SUBTREES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_PIMSM_V2=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_LWTUNNEL=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_HMAC=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_BPF=y
```

- ip a/r

```sh
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp58s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:b6:d0:ba:6e:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.171/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp58s0
       valid_lft 2948sec preferred_lft 2948sec
    inet6 fe80::954a:b70a:2356:9497/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp58s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.0.0/22 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.171 metric 600
```

Comment: You do have `/proc/net/if_inet6` according to your pase though?

Comment: What are you using to manager your network interfaces? And how does `ip a`/`r` look like?

Comment: Hi Tom, yes, I do have `/proc/net/if_inet6`; I added the information to question.

Comment: You only have link-local ipv6 address. So what are you using to manage your network connections? Have you configured it to accept router advertisement / enabled its DHCPv6 client? `sysctl -a | grep accept_ra`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all! I found the answer to this question.

ISP didn't assign me an ipv6 address, now it's alright.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ipv6` module because IPv6 support has been built directly into the core kernel image. See `/proc/config.gz`, where the `CONFIG_IPV6` option is set to "y" (as opposed to "m").

Not having /proc/net/if_inet6 usually means you have manually disabled IPv6 support through the kernel command line, using `ipv6.disable=1` or a similar option. Check `/proc/cmdline` to find out.

Comment: Example Command: `gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep "CONFIG_IPV6"`.

Comment: Thank you! But I can't find `ipv6.disable=1` in the file(`/proc/cmdline`)
```sh
$ cat /proc/cmdline
initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux-lts.img root=/dev/nvme0n1p7
```
And the `CONFIG_IPV6` option has been set to "y":
```sh
$ gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep "CONFIG_IPV6"
CONFIG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTE_INFO=y
CONFIG_IPV6_OPTIMISTIC_DAD=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MIP6=m
CONFIG_IPV6_ILA=m
CONFIG_IPV6_VTI=m
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT=m
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT_6RD=y
CONFIG_IPV6_TUNNEL=m
CONFIG_IPV6_GRE=m
CONFIG_IPV6_FOU=m
CONFIG_IPV6_FOU_TUNNEL=m
```